# Does Samba AD Support Resource-Based Constrained Delegation?

Tags: active-directory, samba

Windows AD supports [resource-based constrained delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview). Is there something similar in samba AD? For example, does cross-realm S4U2Proxy work on Samba AD? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of research, I have found that the MIT krb5 libraries do not support resource based constrained delegation. The devs [have discussed supporting it](http://kerberos.996246.n3.nabble.com/Implementing-RBCD-td49041.html), and there is even [a fork of the krb5 library with a POC](https://github.com/iboukris/krb5/commit/fc3b232a6592834a46308220097019c4ab7d1da2), but it is not yet supported. As Samba AD is based on the krb5 libraries, I highly doubt it is supported. In addition, if the server doing the delegation is on Linux, it will not be able to do delegation even if Samba AD supported it.